# Dynamic Array in C input via terminal

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I am new to C and I was trying to programm a dynamic int Array which gets its values via terminal.
I got it to work but it only works for a few numbers before i get the following error: `realloc(): invalid next size Aborted`. I would like to know why that is
Here is my code so far:

```
void dynamicIntArray(){
    int *dynamicArray = malloc(0);
    int length = 0;

    printf("Please put in your numbers: \n");
    while(1){
        int x;
        scanf("%d", &x);

        if(x == -1){ break; }
        else{
            dynamicArray = realloc(dynamicArray, sizeof(int));
            if(dynamicArray == NULL){ return EXIT_FAILURE; }
            dynamicArray[length++] = x;
        }
    }
}


int main(){
    dynamicIntArray();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The second argument of `realloc` is [the new size of the array in bytes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc)

Comment: Oh ok thanks I thought it expends by this value ok makes sense.

Comment: You did not check the return value of `scanf()`, meaning any use of `x` after that line may invoke undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
realloc(dynamicArray, sizeof(int))
```

With

```
realloc(dynamicArray, length * sizeof(int))
```

The former option will allocate memory for a single `int`. Accessing element at index other than zero invokes undefined behaviour, likely a crash.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution now. I also had to change the index when assigning a new value to `dynamicArray` otherwise it would always hold the default int value at index 0 which makes me think `malloc(0)` is exactly the same as `malloc(1)`.

```
void dynamicIntArray() {
    int *dynamicArray = malloc(0);
    int length = 0;

    printf("Please put in your numbers: \n");

    while(1) {
        int x;
        scanf("%d", &x);

        if(x == -1) { break; }
        else {
            dynamicArray = realloc(dynamicArray, ++length*sizeof(int));

            if(dynamicArray == NULL) { return EXIT_FAILURE; }

            dynamicArray[length-1] = x;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    dynamicIntArray();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't answer your question with a "here is my solution now" response.  It's not really a clear answer.   Think about how others who come to the site are seeing a similar problem and want to know where it is failing.  tstanisl's answer points you to the right place.